# Need a way to take three csv files and put into one as well as remove duplicates and replace values in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python but I need help creating a script that will take in three different csv files, combine them together, remove duplicates from the first column as well as remove any rows that are blank, then change a revenue area to a number.

The three CSV files are setup the same.

The first column is a phone number and the second column is a revenue area (city).

The first column will need all duplicates & blank values removed.
The second column will have values like "Macon", "Marceline", "Brookfield", which will need to be changed to a specific value like:

```
Macon = 1
Marceline = 8
Brookfield = 4
```

And then if it doesn't match one of those values put a default value of 9.

Comment: http://python.org is a great place to start. Please come back when you have a specific hurdle you're having trouble with.

Comment: The normal way is to read all files into some sort of python structures.  Then filter and merge them as needed.  Finally write to a new csv.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Firstly, you'll want to be using the csv library for the "reader" and "writer" functions, so import the csv module.

Then, you'll want to open the new file to be written to, and use the csv.writer function on it.

After that, you'll want to define a set (I name it seen). This will be used to prevent duplicates from being written.

Write your headers (if you need them) to the new file using the writer.

Open your first old file, using csv module's "reader". Iterate through the rows using a for loop, and add the rows to the "seen" set. If a row has been seen, simply "continue" instead of writing to the file. Repeat this for the next two files.

To assign the values to the cities, you'll want to define a dictionary that holds the old names as the keys, and new values for the names as the values.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
import csv

myDict = {'Macon' : 1, 'Marceline' : 8, 'Brookfield' : 4}
seen = set()

newFile = open('newFile.csv', 'wb', newline='') #newline argument will prevent the writer from writing extra newlines, preventing empty rows.
writer = csv.writer(newFile)
writer.writerow(['Phone Number', 'City']) #This will write a header row for you.

#Open the first file, read each row, skip empty rows, skip duplicate rows, change value of "City", write to new file.
with open('firstFile.csv', 'rb') as inFile:
    for row in csv.reader(inFile):
       if any(row):
            row[1] = myDict[row[1]]
            if row in seen:
                continue
            seen.add(row)
            writer.writerow(row)

#Open the second file, read each row, skip if row is empty, skip duplicate rows, change value of "City", write to new file.
with open('secondFile.csv', 'rb') as inFile:
    for row in csv.reader(inFile):
       if any(row):
            row[1] = myDict[row[1]]
            if row in seen:
                continue
            seen.add(row)
            writer.writerow(row)

#Open the third file, read each row, skip empty rows, skip duplicate rows, change value of "City", write to new file.
with open('thirdFile.csv', 'rb') as inFile:
    for row in csv.reader(inFile):
       if any(row):
            row[1] = myDict[row[1]]
            if row in seen:
                continue
            seen.add(row)
            writer.writerow(row)

#Close the output file
newFile.close()
```

I have not tested this myself, but it is very similar to two different programs that I wrote, and I have attempted to combine them into one. Let me know if this helps, or if there is something wrong with it!
-JCoder96

Comment: I think this should help.  I'll tinker with what you provided.  Thanks for the response!